# Google recapthca v2 working locally but not on live website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I've implemented google's recapthca v2(checkbox) on my website(ASP.NET MVC) locally and, it works 100%.
When I tried to copy over project files to my live website, the capthca did not work...

It does render correctly and I can interact with the checkbox, but the validation ALWAYS fails... It is the exact same project as on my localhost how can this be?

And I did change the site and secret keys when i moved files over to live site.

View:

```
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>

        <div class="submit-frm-btn">

            <button class="contact-btn bg-mediumBlue"
                    type="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
```

controller:

```
 public ActionResult SaveForm(ContactUs contactUsForm)
         {
            //getting and setting response from captha
            var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
            string secretkey = "my_secret_key";
            var client = new WebClient();
         
            var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretkey + "&response=" + response  +""));
            var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
            var status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");
            ViewData["Message"] = status ? "Google reCaptcha validation success." : "Google reCaptcha validation failed.";

            //status true  = captcha successful
            if (status)
            {
               
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
```

When captcha is correct and modelstate is valid, is save contact to DB. Note that this code works locally, I can successfully validate the capthca but the validation always fails on my live site.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: does google's response include any error codes?

Comment: @Vvamp how do I check?

Comment: I dont see any error codes, the validation just comes back as false..

Comment: The response should have an 'error codes' variable, which could contain errors; https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-response

Comment: no error codes, get request comes back as 200 from google

Comment: have you tried testing it in a seperate browser?

Comment: yes i Have, safari and microsoft edge, same issue

Comment: I'm not sure then. I don't see anything obviously wrong here, sorry

Comment: Found something very stange now... to get the response from my live site i tested the api call in postman with the correct secrect key and response parameters. I got a success: true" back. but yet the front-end displays validation failed? but in the code above that seems to be impossible? how does this happen...

Comment: anyoneplease ? :(

Comment: If you print the url right before actually requesting it in your saveform function, are the variables set correctly?

Comment: Yes it is, I copied the api endpoint and parameters from my live site and tested the exact same request in postman, and the 'success' token came back as true.... but yet front-end displays validation failed? once agian, this works locally but not on live site, I have exhausted all my options and dont know what to do at this point...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245591/discussion-between-vvamp-and-kyle).

Comment: still no resolution... if anyone can assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Every time I copied the local project files to the server, I swapped the config files because of the connection strings... And exactly that was the problem.

I assume Recaptcha has written in values into the local config file. It was the last thing I expected because I did not download a package for ReCaptcha or anything... Rookie mistake I guess.

Hope this helps anyone in the future